# NoSuchMethodException when inherit abstract class in Activity

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-fragments

I'm facing this issue on my apps :

```
Caused by java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> []
       at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2332)
       at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1728)
       at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.a(Fragment.java:15)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainer.instantiate(FragmentContainer.java)
at com.example.DefAct.colorStatusBar(DefAct.java)
       at com.example.MainActivity.initWorkers(MainActivity.java)
```

Which caused this error :

```
Caused by androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$e: Unable to instantiate fragment f.a.a.a.x.u.a: could not find Fragment constructor
       at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.a(Fragment.java:66)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainer.instantiate(FragmentContainer.java)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$6.instantiate(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2)
at com.example.DefAct.colorStatusBar(DefAct.java)
       at com.example.MainActivity.initWorkers(MainActivity.java)
```

So, I have an abstract class DefAct.kt :

```
abstract class DefAct: AppCompatActivity() {
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            colorStatusBar()
    }
private fun colorStatusBar() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            window.statusBarColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.blue)
        }
    }
}
```

Then, I call this abstract class into my MainActivity.kt :

```
class MainActivity: DefAct(){
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
}
.....
}
```

Some ideas that I think might become a solution for my problem :

- Changing the colorStatusBar() method on MyDefaultAct.kt into public
- Create empty constructor

Things I've done :

- Read documentation about the abstract class, fragment and its constructor
- Trying to create a constructor but my Activity doesn't have any fragments except for only calling

> dialog.show(supportFragmentManager, SomeTags.TAG)

I don't know exactly how to reproduce the test case that caused these logs. But when I read the log, the exception appeared right after calling the colorStatusBar(). Please kindly help me to solve this issue, I've been struggling for 4 hours. If I missed something with my code, please kindly tell me. Thank you

Comment: What is the `window` variable?

Comment: it's to set the status bar color @Quadslab

Comment: It's just weird since I don't have the exact fragment inside my MainActivity.kt. I only have dialog to display which not even inherit any kinds of fragments, only calling it like this `dialog.show(supportFragmentManager, SomeTags.TAG)` @Quadslab

Comment: Have you tried leaving out `colorStatusBar()` and if that works `... = ContextCompat.getColor(...)`?

Comment: @Quadslab what do you mean? I think both are the same, whether I create a specific method for the color or I just declare the color with `ContextCompat.getColor()` directly into the onCreate

Comment: I mean leaving that out, maybe it has to with `getColor()`, have you correctly installed `androidx.appcompat:appcompat`?

Comment: @Quadslab yes, I installed the correct one