# Is it possible to use newInstance() on an Activity in Android Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-fragments

I'm new to android actually. I'm now confused about how to implementing a newInstance() inside a fragment. I have 2 fragments and 1 Activity here :

- Fragment A as an Abstract Class
- Fragment B as a Main Fragment Class that contain parameters
- MainActivity.kt as the Activity

So I got an error log like this :

```
Caused by androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$e: Unable to instantiate fragment : could not find Fragment constructor
............
Caused by java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> []
       at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0
```

Based on the log, I think the problem is on the fragment that I haven't initialized any 0-arg constructor. So because of this, I want to add a companion object for newInstance() inside my fragment but I can't, here's my FragmentA.kt and FragmentB.kt :

**FragmentA.kt**

```
abstract class FragmentA: BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

companion object {
fun newInstance(): FragmentA{
    return FragmentA()  //Got a red mark here, because I cannot create newInstance() in an abstract class
}
}
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setStyle(DialogFragment...,getStyle)
    }

}
```

**FragmentB.kt**

```
class FragmentB(val Parameterss: AnyParametersHere) : FragmentA() {
    
    companion object {
    fun newInstance(): FragmentB{
        return FragmentB()  //Got a red mark here, because it requires parameter inside the FragmentB()
    }
    }
        override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        val dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState)
        ..................................................................
        return dialog

        }
    
    }
```

**MainActivity.kt**
In the MainActivity.kt, can I add newInstance() to its companion object or not? If not, what's the best solution for this case?

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

companion object {
        fun newInstance(): MainActivity {
            return newInstance()
        }
    }
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    ...................................
    val fragmentB= FragmentB(this)
        fragmentB.show(supportFragmentManager, FragmentB.TAG)

    }

}
```

I'm confused tho, please if you have any better solutions I would like to appreciate it. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

There are many different things wrong here, I would suggest you read more on this topic. I will help clear your doubts. Let us start with your code.

Firstly **FragmentA**, `FragmentA` is an Abstract class and thus when you are getting the error

> Unable to instantiate fragment

You cannot create an instance of an abstract class because it does not have a complete implementation. If it does, it should not be marked abstract in the first place. You should extend from Abstract Classes which you are doing so in `FragmentB`

Now coming to **FragmentB**

```kotlin
class FragmentB(val Parameterss: AnyParametersHere) : FragmentA() {
```

As you can see inside you are accepting parameters inside its constructor. Now coming to your `newInstance()` method. The code is as follows:

```kotlin
fun newInstance(): FragmentB{
        return FragmentB()
    }
```

And you rightly got an error or a read mark here because you created an instance of `FragmentB` but you did not pass any parameters in its constructors which you put in its constructor.

Now coming to the right pattern for it, we use `newInstance` usually in Fragment when we need to do pass `arguments` from one fragment to the other and we do by using `Bundles` which we assign via `newInstance`

Here is a sample code for that.

```kotlin
companion object {
        fun newInstance() = FragmentB().apply {
            arguments = Bundle().apply {
                // Put values here in a key value pair.
            }
        }
    }
```

And then you get an instance of `FragmentB` as `FragmentB.newInstance()`. You will have to read more on this topic. There are more than one ways to transfer data between Fragments.

Coming to your **MainActivity** you do not need `newInstance` here as between Activities you can directly use `Intents` and transfer data that way if needed.

Comment: But to create newInstance() in FragmentB, I need to add parameters inside it right @che10 ? like this 

`companion object {
        fun newInstance() = FragmentB(parameters).apply {
            arguments = Bundle().apply {
                // Put values here in a key value pair.
            }
        }
    }`

Comment: Yes you can add parameters using a key value pair by using `put` function in that block. Like `putString()` or `putInt()` as such.

Comment: sorry I'm a bit confused, so I understand that I have to add parameters using `putString()` or `putInt()` , but I still got red mark in `fun newInstance() = FragmentB().apply {` . I don't how to fix this. Because the FragmentB() needs parameter inside it like FragmentB(parameters = ) and I haven't initialized the parameters beforehand

Comment: If I might say, my case is kind of similar to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67899930/nosuchmethodexception-when-inherit-abstract-class-in-activity

Comment: Could you please clarify what kind of parameters are you adding? You need to add them according to their type. Like if it is an Integer then you will use `putInt()` if it is a String then you will use `putString()` and so on. Your `newInstance()` method will be modified as such. Let us say you have to add string then it will be `newInstance(stringToAdd: String)` and then inside it you can add it as `putString("Your Key here", stringToAdd)`

Comment: the parameters inside FragmentB() is from interface class. so the class will look like this `class FragmentB( val interfaceClass: MyInterfaceClass) : FragmentA(){}`

Comment: It is not recommended that two fragments communicate directly @LieAnaWijaya. I suggest you take a look at [this link](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate). You are better off using a shared ViewModel. But, if you still insist on using interfaces then your structure would be somewhat like this. Create an interface in A, and pass the data to the Main Activity and then your activity passes the data onto B.

Answer (score 0):

FragmentB’s constructor must *not* have parameters. Fragments are recreated by the OS using the empty constructor. Your `newInstance()` function can pass data to the Fragment via a bundle, and the OS will restore that same bundle if it recreates your fragment. Use the `requireBundle()` to get your parameters and assign them to properties in your first entry point in your Fragment (`onCreateView()`, `onViewCreated()`, or `onCreateDialog()`).

A common mistake is to give your Fragment two constructors, one empty and one with the parameters you need, and using the one with parameters in `newInstance()`. The problem with this is your parameters will be lost when the OS recreates your Fragment with the empty constructor. The OS only restores the Bundle, not the parameters of a constructor, because it exclusively uses the empty constructor.

Note that bundle arguments must be one of the supported types, which are all the "primitive" classes, Strings, Parcelables, arrays of any of the above, and Serializeables.

Example of how you would do this with a fragment that needs some values:

```
class MyFragment: Fragment() {

    companion object {
        private const val SOME_ARG_KEY = "SOME_ARG_KEY"
        private const val SOME_OTHER_ARG_KEY = "SOME_OTHER_ARG_KEY"

        fun newInstance(someArgument: Long, someOtherArgument: String)
            = MyFragment().apply { 
                arguments = bundleOf(
                    SOME_ARG_KEY to someArgument,
                    SOME_OTHER_ARG_KEY to someOtherArgument,
                )
            }
    }

    lateinit var someArgument: Long
    lateinit var someOtherArgument: String

    //...

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        with (requireArguments()) {
            someArgument = getLong(SOME_ARG_KEY)
            someOtherArgument = getString(SOME_OTHER_ARG_KEY)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I got it, but do you have any examples or references that I can follow to?
Thank you

Comment: @LieAnaWijaya I added an example.